# Echo text with images inside php for loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I have a PHP script which gets all of the images in folder and I would like to add the filenames in a

tag under them.

Tried GetElementById but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:Works now

PHP here:

```
<?php
$files = glob("img/*.*");
  for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
      $image = $files[$i];
      $filename = pathinfo($image);
      echo '
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
            <img  class="img-responsive" src="'.$image .'"/>
        </a>

      <p>' . $filename['filename'] .'</p>

      </div> ' ; }
?>
```

Comment: why not adding the text in php? id=imagename has t obe id="imagename"

Comment: `getElementById` only gets one single element, as there should only be one single element with a given ID. You're creating multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @JarlikStepsto My bad, mistyped it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$image` already stores a path to your file.

For example `$image` can be `/upload/images/picture.jpg`.
Then to get filename (which is `picture.jpg`) you can use [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) function:

```
echo '
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="'.$image .'"/>
        </a>
        <p>' . basename($image) . '</p>
  </div>';
```

If you need to echo full file path - omit `basename`:

```
<p>' . $image . '</p>
```

And as already mentioned - using **same** id for several elements is a bad idea. Ids must be **unique** on a page. If you don't really need `id`s - just remove them as I did in my answer.

Comment: Where should i put the split function or something else to get rid of the extension in the end?

Comment: Before `echo` or try to use `pathinfo` function.

Comment: Thank you, pathinfo function worked. Edited the question.